# Please help with suggestions for existential or philosophical inspired team names?

Tags: existentialism

I imagine that this question will be frowned upon, but it's a bit of fun and hopefully, we can have some fun with this.

I am doing the Mongol Rally in 2023 in a red Suzuki Alto and need to come up with a team and car name. I want the team and car name to be thought-provoking and maybe have an existential/philosophical theme/context.

So, do you have any ideas for a team and car name?

Comment: *Wheels of Time* with *Eternal Return* could work.

Comment: @Michael - excellent!

Comment: Ghost in the Machine?  Question Assumptions?  Some questions are unanswerable? Virtual Thought Problem? Logically Inconsistent?  Minimal Coherency?  Inverted Spectrum?

Comment: @Dcleve - nice, I am a physicist, so i do really like juxtaposing philosophical ideas.

Comment: I am not well read on Nietzsche, these are mostly from Phil of Mind, intuitive thought problem philosophy, and Socratic methodology.

Comment: The Solip Sisters? of course there's only one of them...

Comment: You could call the car the Ship of Theseus and the crew the Paradoxicals, though I don’t know how many people would get it. Or if you want something even more classical, try Democritus and the Auto-Crats

Comment: "Amor Fati" maybe?

Comment: @Richard - beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a language transformer, which can be helpful in brainstorming. I used GPT-J at [TextSynth](https://textsynth.com/playground.html), which gave me *The Death Crew* and *The Worldview Warriors* within the first few tries. I cannot say whether these are taken, but if you try enough, you should be able to get something novel. Another popular model is [GPT-3](https://openai.com/) (sign-in required), which is more powerful. The key to successful use of language transformers is in prompt-crafting. Generally, the more context you provide (up to the memory limit), the better the result. An example prompt:

> Welcome to the Mongol Rally of existential, philosophical wonder, where purpose is both found and lost. Many thought-provoking teams will be finding their presence here, but will any achieve permanence? Making a fierce entry with its red Suzuki Alto, a new Nietzsche-inspired team from Missing Valley, the

Note how the prompt ends in pregnancy. This allows the language transformer to take over from exactly that point in the sentence. While not always necessary, this approach can often get the desired result more up-front. Also, remember to check what it gives you is not already taken or otherwise coming from a copyrighted source. Searching the Web is probably a wise idea before officially using something it gives you. The examples I gave may well be in use out there, so be careful.